# Laravel 7 eloquent whereIn and where not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a record in my database that looks like this:

```
id | roles
----------
1  | ["test"]
```

I do this eloquent query:

```
UserModel::withTrashed()
      ->whereIn('roles', ['test'])
      ->where('id', 1)
      ->exists();
```

This returns `false` what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your attribute `roles` is JSON, then you can't use the SQL `IN` (wrapped by `whereIn`).

Comment: I agree with @Shizzen83, I don't think you should query db by exact JSON either.

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use?

Comment: @Shizzen83 laravel 7.x

Comment: Do you mind replacing your JSON attribute by an integer? (only in database) If no, I have a solution

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this exists:

```
->whereJsonContains('roles', ['test'])
```

Then it works great.